# Need a Persistent Data solution for my hit counter asp.net dilemma

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a hit counter I'm trying to implement on my website. I'm trying to figure out a way to send the persistent data hit count number from one webform to another webform. Normally, I would use something like session state or a cookie. My problem is when I display the webpage the first time, the counter doesn't appear, it only appears when i navigate back and forth between the main page and the page i'm counting. I'm guessing this is because everytime, I leave the website and re-vist, the session state ends and a new one is created, hence why the data is gone. So sessionstate is out of the question.

I thought creating a cookie might be a solution, but I realize that anyone who FIRST TIME come to my page, will still have the problem of no hit counter being displayed the first time they visit. My question is there anyway for persistent data to be simply  displayed the first time new users visit  my webpage.

The page with the counter

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string field1 = (string)(Session["field1"]);
        Label1.Text = field1;
    }
```

The page that has the counter value i'm trying to get from

```
  using (conn)
        {
            //open the connection
            conn.Open();
            //send the query and store the results in a sqldatareader
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                //set the text of our label to the current # of hits
                lblHits.Text = "Default Page Hits - " +  
                rdr["Hits"].ToString();

            }
           Session["field1"] = rdr["Hits"].ToString(); 

        }
```

my asp.net control

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" class="viewNumber" runat="server" 
 EnableViewState="False" ></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Just to see if I understand correctly, You want to count for every user the number of times they visited the page?

Comment: I just want the count to display correctly every time the page is first loaded. If you notice, the method I tried. The count is NEVER displayed the first time the page is loaded, only AFTER i navigate back and forth from the links, does the count number appear and start counting correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure the [`Session`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.session(v=vs.110).aspx) collection holds a value from the moment a user visits your page you can leverage the `Session_Start` method that is wired in the [global.asax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx) of your project and gives access to the [`HttpApplication`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication(v=vs.110).aspx) instance.

`Session_Start` is run once when a user has no session yet and a new session is being created. You have access to `Session` because that property exposes a HttpSessionState instance on the `HttpApplication`

The code example you provided is not complete but I expect if you have something like this you should be close.

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select Hits from application", conn))
            {
                //open the connection
                conn.Open();
                //send the query and store the results in a sqldatareader
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Session["field1"] = rdr["Hits"];
                }
                else
                {
                    // no record found, so start at 0
                    // maybe init the row in the table as well...
                    Session["field1"] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice that this would be really application global state, so instead of filling Session you can use [`Application`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.application(v=vs.110).aspx). The code to set the value for the key can move to `Application_Start` in that case.

Comment: Really awesome. I'm definitely going to try this. Thank you.